# How to make sure that the tap function works in appium for android apps?

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to tap on an Element on 1st screen[say an element named Views] and upon it's click a new screen opens and there I want to tap on an element named[Expandable Lists].

So on 2nd attempt I want to use Tap function to the operation for me. **Tap()** function is not working whereas using **.click()** the tap does work. Please have a look at the code that I've written till this step:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions.*;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.TapOptions.tapOptions;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption.element;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.WaitOptions.waitOptions;

public class Gestures extends Parent {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();

    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text= 'Views']").click();

    TouchActions t = new TouchActions(driver);
    WebElement expandList= driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']");
    //t.tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(webElement)));
    // for element we need to import it's library just like we did 
    //for         the WebElement

    t.singleTap(expandList);
    t.perform(); 


    TouchAction(driver).tap(tapOptions()
    .withElement(element(expandList)))
    .waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(250))).perform();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **click()** instead of **tap()**.

> To make sure click() is working fine, you can check if your expected screen appear after the clicking the button.

Comment: Yes, the click() did work for me. Since I'm a newbie to automation using Appium so just curious to know how this tap() will work.

Thanks for the reply @suban